# Why is not the day of the week formated in long date format for all languages?

Tags: c#, .net, date-format

We have used `date.ToString ("D")` for formatting the date. But when we globalizat the application to other languages ​​we encounter problems. We expect the day of the week to appear when we use the long date format, but it's not lake so for all languages. According http://www.basicdatepicker.com/samples/cultureinfo.aspx, it is far from all language that print out day a week for the long date format. How should we do to format the date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need an explicit format, specify it like so;

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
string s = date.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy");
```

According to the MSDN doco, the "D" format specifier is affected by the Calendar, which is Culture specific.

You shouldn't make assumptions about string formatting or Date display in particular, when internationalising.

Comment: But the application are translated to many languages, and don't want to write special formating for each translation. Why is the formatting so different in all languages? Here in Sweden, the long date format only works in body text, not when the date stands on its own as it should do in this application.

Comment: You don't *have* to write formatting for each language, that's what DateTime.ToString("D") does for you. If you want the format to appear the same *regardless* of language, then follow my example. You can't have both!